# Send one/multiple files to multiple servers

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I often need to send files from my computer to a bunch of servers, who are on the same domain and on Windows. The files are always uploaded at the same place (like `C:\foo\bar`) in each server.

Now, you will be scared by what I'll say. I upload each file remotely by RDP (mounting my local disk) and placing them manually in the location. I found this really annoying, since we've got 45 servers on Windows in my company.

I would like to have a nice UI, with my list of servers, and an explorer to send remotely, letting me make the choice of which of them I will work on.

I'm not against the use of scripts, but it would be nice to have an UI for this situation

Comment: Is it always the same list of servers? Is the shareing via remote desktop the only way to transfer files between the machines (due to a securty guideline?)

Comment: Yeah, always the same list (sometimes we add one...).
And yep, actually our guideline forbids us any ftp/other transfert since we are working in production. Of course, when we need to send big files we use ftp, but files I want to send are tiny vbs scripts.

Comment: Just an random shot: could you not create a scheduled task on each server that copies the files from a common shared drive (like YourComputer/C$/vbs_scripts) every couple of hours?

Comment: Now that you say this, we have a mean of transfert by ftp on each server. 
Let me explain : 
Each morning our healthcheck script generate a .txt, this .txt is sent (by ftp) on a remote server (on our domain) and this server send a mail with all the .txt.
Now the fact is, when I need to modify the structure of the script, I need to do it for the 50 servers. So yes, we can FTP. It's my bad to not have saying this before, i totally forget. 
What advice can you give me ? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After the comments (and if I understood you correctly): 
Use the FTP cmdline tools to process a textfile with the necessary ftp commands. Here should http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx?mfr=true 
be helpful. Or you could use my favorite scripting engine Autohotkey. 
EDIT: typo ..

Comment: Methinks you meant "commands", unless your FTP server used to be run by the British Army.

Comment: @cpast: sure ... you could also use commandos, but they are just to epxensive. But it would be very secure. Just use 50 soldies to do the task... would also increase the overall security :-)

Comment: Thanks dude, will take a look at it. 
Anyway I will try to share my scripts folders, so I can automate it with a batch.